# Flutter ListView Item Click y pasar datos

Tags: flutter, dart

como va? como soy nuevo en Flutter y no hay muchos ejemplos, quería saber como podría seleccionar un ítem de mi ListView y pasar los datos a una nueva pantalla para hacer el perfil del objeto seleccionado.

El código de mi ListView es:

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @required
  final Text title; //Titulo a mostrar
  @required
  final Future<List<Negocio>> list;
  Page({this.title, this.list});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: this.title,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Negocio>>(
        future: list,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                    onTap: () {
//ACA SUPONGO QUE IRIA ITEM SELECCIONADO.
                    },
                  );


                  Negocio negocio = snapshot.data[index];
                  return NegocioItem(
                    negocio: negocio,
                  );
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },

      ),
    );
  }
}

class NegocioItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @required
  final Negocio negocio;
  NegocioItem({this.negocio});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      //onTap: _launchURL,
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(
                    negocio.imageUrl,
                    width: 90,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      negocio.title,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(negocio.description),
              /* Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Text(
                  negocio.fecha,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.green),
                ),
              )*/
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El Widget `ListTile` no se está usando debes eliminarlo. Simplemente haces un return al widget `NegocioItem` es aquí en donde puedes hacer la acción de llamar a otra pantalla y enviar los datos, por ejemplo:

**Page**

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Negocio negocio = snapshot.data[index];
        return NegocioItem(
        onTap: (){ // Esto se ejecutará mediante un callback y enviará a la página detalle
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(negocio: negocio)), 
            );
        },
        negocio: negocio,
        );

    });
```

**NegocioItem**

```
class NegocioItem extends StatelessWidget {
  NegocioItem({this.negocio, this.onTap});

  @required
  final Negocio negocio;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap, //Esto hace un CallBack
      ...
```

Para el ejemplo voy a crear un `DetailPage` que recibe el objeto `negocio` como atributo.

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
    DetailPage({this.negocio});

    final Negocio negocio;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Detail Page"),
        ),
        body: Center(
        child: Text(negocio.title),
        ),
    );
    }
}
```